# Profile Mapping when installing a managed package using Ant

Tags: managed-package, deployment, profile, ant

When installing a managed packages via Ant, is there any way to map managed package profiles to profiles that already exist in the Salesforce org?

I have the following profiles in the Salesforce Org.
[image]

I am trying to reproduce the mapping functionality that is performed when installing a managed packaged via an installation Url.
[image]

I have looked into using Apex code but DML operations are not allowed on the Profile sObject.
[image]